# Is there some public gentoo repository for installing java-related stuff?

Tags: java, gentoo, repository

Is there some public gentoo repository for installing java-related stuff?
Could be layman or whatever.

Things I'm interested in are: apache-activemq, apache-solr, fusesource etc.

Answer (score 1):

The layman repository [java](http://gpo.zugaina.org/Overlays/java) contains a lot of java packages, but fuse is the only one in your list that can be found there.

I suggest you take a look at http://gpo.zugaina.org/. There you can search for ebuilds and a lot of overlays are included.